# Biztalk FileAdapter Errror when using Dynamic Send Port and UNC

Tags: .net, biztalk

I am using a Dynamic Send Port in Biztalk 2006 and i am trying to write to a Windows Share (UNC) but get "Access is denied".

The Biztalk host in-process-user got all permission needed at the given folder. I can manually create a new file in the destination but not when using Biztalk.

Does the FileAdapter use another host-user ?(which i have not added to the permission list on the unc-folder)

The Error:

 `Error details: The FILE send adapter cannot open file \int.company.as\Biztalk\CodeNA\ImageName_123456_20080227T230000_.xml for writing.
 Details: Access is denied.`

Edited:
A work around will be to write locally first and then use File.Move(), but I cannot understand why the above doesnt work. it works on a Share on my local laptop..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, problem solved...
The reason is that the File Adapter can run under another Host-process. (and this other hostprocess did not have permissions to the specific folder..)

I thought the FileAdapter followed the credentials of the Orchestration, - but no...

Comment: Dynamic send ports don't really change the dynamics of how adapters execute at that level, so the adapter call will still execute in the context dictated by the configured send handlers, not under the execution context of the orchestration (unless they happen to be the same).